# Eclipse Tasks - only local repo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, repository, mylyn, tasklist

Im using Eclipse's Task List(aka Mylyn) and when I create new task I have to always choose Local Repository, is there any way to by-pass this step? (I will never use any other Repository). I create a lot of tasks and its slowing me down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a task, don't select **Task...**, but select **Local Task** or just press **Insert** in the **Task List View**.